# Synchronizing threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

So I have a code:

```
public void runThreads(int number)
{
    List<Thread> threadList = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        Thread t = new MyThread(getRandomPerson(),i);
        threadList.add(t);
    }

    for (Thread x : threadList)
    {
        x.start();
    }
}
```

So I am adding threads to my list of threads and then starting this threads.
This is MyThread class:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread
{
    Person person;
    int number;

    public MyThread(Person person, int number)
    {
        this.person = person;
        this.number = number;
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            synchronized (this)
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(number + "\t" + person.getSurname());
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(number + "\t" + person.toString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to make a program which creates the threads, adds them to the list, invokes them but each thread should wait until the previous ended its task.
So output should be like :

```
1 Surname
/** Waitning second */
1 person.toString()
/** Waiting second*/
And then the second thread start invoking:
2 Surname
....
```

How to achieve this using `synchronized`? I tried different ways to use `synchronized` but it failed.

Comment: Why use threads if you want a strictly synchronous output?

Comment: I was typing that question exactly.

Comment: @Dariusz It is a task I was given, and it does not depend on me.

Comment: if this is a homework/interview task then I guess that is fine, but otherwise makes little sense.  If it is a real task, then I'd question the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyThread extends Thread
{

    private static Object lock = new Object();

...
            synchronized (lock)
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(number + "\t" + person.getSurname());
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(number + "\t" + person.toString());
            }
...
```

That way you will get the same person's surname and toString() in order. You won't enforce strict ordering on the people, person 7 may still go before person 1.

Comment: I tried that with the lock on MyThread.class and the same behavior ensued. Any difference in using a shared lock instead of locking on the class? Considering the fact that there is no other method in this class which is synchronized?

Comment: I don't know if `.class` returns the same object every time. It may be a copy.

Comment: Class literals will always return the same instance. It is explicitly stated in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6) that a `synchronized static` method will use the same object as `synchronized(ClassName.class)` if `ClassName` is the name of the class containing the method. Even `Class.forName(…)` will always return the same object for the same name and caller.

Comment: @Holger I dug a little bit into the subject... And it's not that obvious. It should work in this case, but if `.class` is called from different classes there could be problems. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23473997/does-class-property-of-an-object-always-return-the-same-instance

Comment: The main issue is *not* that multiple classes might get different `Class` instances, the reason to use a lock object like in your example is that differencet classes *can* access and synchronize on the same `Class` object. You usually want to have the full control over the synchronization and limit the `synchronized` code as much as possible. Therefore you use an `Object` stored in a `private` field to sync on.

Answer (score 1):

You need a common lock - at the moment you are synchronizing on `this`, which is different for each thread. Try something like:

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();
```

and synchronize on that static (therefore shared) variable instead.

Comment: Are you sure this will ensure the order? I just tried synchronzing on the lock and while it made sure that it printed the 2 statements inside the sync block together, the order from 0-9 is not maintained. Are did i do it wrong?

Comment: @prabugp no the order will be random, which is kind of the purpose of multithreading. If you need each of the tasks to run in a predefined order, it would be much simpler not to use threads at all.

Comment: don't shoot the messenger. My interest was piqued by OP's question and i'm just trying to find out if I have missed Thread 101. :)

Comment: @prabugp Sorry I didn't mean to be agressive!

Comment: No offense taken.. I take it that there is no way we can achieve what OP wants (apart from the obviously stupid t.join immediately after t.start)? No amount of locking, using any of the concurrency features available?

Comment: @prabugp joining after starting would preseve order and would be the simplest way (therefore not stupid)... after not using threads at all! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you  *must* use threads and if you *must* have order of execution, then you can do a `t.join()` immediately after `t.start()` - this will ensure the following flow:

```
- Main Thread
      - loop
      - start child thread
      - wait for child thread to finish
      - continue loop
- Exit Main thread
```

But, as pointed before, you don't need threads to do this since you can see that there is absolutely no gain from this approach (apart from academical) and it's detrimental in fact.

And special thanks to @assylias.